# Zend Framework with modular structure + Doctrine 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I use Zend Framework with modules for my applications and I am interested in integrating Doctrine 2 in the same fashion:

A module contains:

- controllers
- models
- views
- helpers

The problem with Doctrine 2 is that it requires to have an entity directory along with a proxy directory. I want the entities directory to be the models directory from my modular structure and based on my research I haven't found a solution.

Currently, with a default module the metadata implementation looks like this:

```
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default/models'));
```

If I want to add a new module, let's say "cms" I have no way of managing the models there with Doctrine.

Is there anyone that has a solution for the problem ?

Comment: I know there is an upcoming WEBINAR: Zend Framework v1 + Doctrine v2 on 14-Dec-2010 http://www.zend.com/en/company/news/event/webinar-zend-framework-v1-doctrine-v2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some hours of work I came up with the correct solution. To be noted that the newDefaultAnnotationDriver, setProxyDir and setProxyNamespace methods of Doctrine's \ORM\Configuration class can receive also array parameters.

This being said, you need to pass arrays with model paths for every module and it will work

Answer (score 0):

I have my proxies (auto-generated) in an application level folder, here's my directory structure:

```
/project
    /application
        /domain
            /proxies
        /configs
        /modules
            /blog
                /controllers
                /views
                /domain
                    /entities
                    /services
                    /repositories
    /library
    /public
    /data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create bootstrap file for each module

```
<?php
class User_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'User_',
            'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/modules/user',
            ));
            return $autoloader;
    }
}
```

and put this in the default bootsrap to load default module models

```
protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Default_',
            'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/modules/default',
            ));
            return $autoloader;
    }
```

it will work fine

Comment: Yes, things changed since I've posted the question. Now there are different solutions to the problem. When I wrote this Doctrine was still in beta and Zend Framework did not have module bootstraps yet :)